# TSQL - Error when running a procedure within a transaction where the procedure includes a transaction

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, transactions, try-catch

Within a stored procedure I have a try catch block with a transaction which will commit if control never passes to the catch otherwise will rollback if there's an error and control does pass to the catch block.

I'm running this stored procedure from within a transaction, as per the below example:

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE sp_test
 AS
 BEGIN
     BEGIN TRY
         BEGIN TRAN
             DECLARE @var INT = 1
             IF @var <> 2 
                 BEGIN
                     RAISERROR('error', 16,1)
                 END
         COMMIT
     END TRY
     BEGIN CATCH
         ROLLBACK
         PRINT 'Rolled back'
     END CATCH
 END


 BEGIN TRAN

 EXEC sp_test
```

When I run this, I'm seeing the error

> Msg 266, Level 16, State 2, Procedure sp_test, Line 0 [Batch Start Line 7]
>   Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT statements. Previous count = 1, current count = 0.

But I don't understand why.

I'm starting a transaction outside of the stored procedure. I'm then going into the SP and beginning another transaction. Once control passes to the catch block, both transactions should be rolled back so transaction count should be 0.

Obviously there's a gap in my understanding here.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Where is your `COMMIT` after `EXEC sp_test`? Also, using a transaction outside of an SP that uses transactions is pointless. There is no such thing as nested transactions in SQL Server. [A SQL Server DBA myth a day: (26/30) nested transactions are real](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/a-sql-server-dba-myth-a-day-2630-nested-transactions-are-real/)

Answer (score 2):

This behaviour is by design. Whenever a transaction is started, the @@TRANCOUNT session variable will increase one, and when a transaction is committed, it decreases one. However, when a transaction rolls back, it rolls back the all nested transactions. So in your case, the rollback in your catch will roll back the 2 nested transactions and @@TRANCOUNT will become 0. This will cause the caller throw the mismatch transaction count exception.

To avoid this issue, you can check @@TRANCOUNT in your SP and only start a new transaction when it is 0 and set a flag (a local variable) to indicate that, e.g. @new_tarn=1. Then you commit or rollback only when @new_tran=1.

Comment: Also in the catch, you need to rethrow the exception so the caller has a chance to catch it and rollback the transaction if the caller starts it.